# Test equals for RDD while defining mock's behavior with Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, apache-spark, mockito

I am writing unit test for some java spark program with Mockito, I got problem when I try to define the behavior of the method of a mocked object like:

```
when(mock.method(someRDD)).thenReturn(0);
```

Since RDD doesn't re-implements equals() function, the mocked behavior works only the rdd passed in the methods is the same reference of this "someRDD".

I wonder if there is any way to customize the "equals()" check behavior in Mockito in mocking methods ? or maybe I should use some other mock framework instead?

Comment: Try to make the action first on RDD and then try to compare as then you will get a Java object

Comment: The mocked interface of the to-test function uses RDD as arguments, it cannot be simply made to Map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write your own [`ArgumentMatcher`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.8.9/org/mockito/ArgumentMatcher.html) to correlate between the passed argument and what you expect. Assuming it's just a straight-forward comparison between the RDD's fields, you can use Mockito's built in [`refEq`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.8.9/org/mockito/ArgumentMatchers.html#refEq(T,%20java.lang.String...)) matcher that uses reflection and just compares each field individually:

```
when(mock.method(refEq(someRDD))).thenReturn(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this https://github.com/holdenk/spark-testing-base for testing with spark rdds. Also, here is a tutorial on how to use it. http://www.jesse-anderson.com/2016/04/unit-testing-spark-with-java/

This will do what you are looking for. Usually the test will look like the following ...

```
    JavaRDD<A> inputRdd = jsc().parallelizePairs(inputData);
    JavaRDD<B> transformedRdd = someMethod(inputRdd);

    JavaRDD<B> expectedRdd = jsc().parallelize(expectedData);

    JavaRDDComparisons.assertRDDEquals(transformedRdd, expectedRdd);
```

However, note that, as far as I remember, there can be clashes with the version of the glassfish or other maven dependencies that you might be using. To get around this I kept the tests in a separate project.

EDIT: If testing pair RDDs you need to add a tag like so ...

```
    ClassTag<Tuple2<K, V>> tag = scala.reflect.ClassTag$.MODULE$.apply(Tuple2.class);
    JavaRDDComparisons.assertRDDEquals(JavaRDD.fromRDD(JavaPairRDD.toRDD(transformedRdd), tag),
                                       JavaRDD.fromRDD(JavaPairRDD.toRDD(expectedRdd), tag));
```

Comment: This information is interesting, thanks. However, it can hardly solve my problem, that I cannot inject my equal-testing code into the mockito test framework.

Comment: Ah, ok I see, sorry

Comment: Please don't say sorry, I am very grateful for your reply.